# Show that equivalent norms implies that an isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces. A bijective linear map $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism if both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous.

> Question: Suppose that $\| \cdot \|_{\alpha}$ and $\| \cdot
>  \|_{\beta}$ are equivalent norms on a vector space $X.$ Show that
>   there is an isomorphism from $(X,\| \cdot \|_{\alpha})$ onto $(X,\|
>  \cdot \|_{\beta}).$

My attempt:

Define the identity map $I_X : (X,\| \cdot \|_{\alpha}) \rightarrow (X, \| \cdot \|_{\beta})$ such that $I_X(x) = x$ for all $x \in X.$

Clearly $I_X$ is a linear bijection. I wish to show that $I$ and $I^{-1}$ are bounded.

Since $\| \cdot \|_{\alpha}$ and $\| \cdot \|_{\beta}$ are equivalent, there exists $c_1>0$ and $c_2>0$ such that 
$$c_1 \| x \|_{\alpha} \leq \| x \|_{\beta} \leq c_2 \| x \|_{\alpha}$$ for $x \in X.$

Note that $\| x \|_{\beta} = \|Ix \|_{\beta} \leq c_2 \|x \|_{\alpha}$ implies that $\| I \| \leq c_2,$ hence $I$ is bounded.

Further note that $c_1 \| x \|_{\alpha} = c_1 \| I^{-1}x\|_{\alpha} \leq \|x\|_{\beta}$ implies that $\| I^{-1} \| \leq \frac{1}{c_1},$ hence $I^{-1}$ is bounded.

Therefore, $I$ is an isomorphism.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me, but it might be worth mentioning that $I_X$ is linear because it is the identity